# C++ / Uncrustify / Indenting base class specifications

Tags: c++, uncrustify

How do I setup uncrustify so that this code:

```
static const class Example
    : Int1
    , Int2
    , Int3
```

looks like this:

```
static const class Example
: Int1
, Int2
, Int3
```

I can not find any option which does only indent the derived classes.

Comment: I cant see different betwin first and second codes !

Comment: First code has a tab in front of Int1, Int2, Int3 and second code not.

Comment: @ViTo, Code is indented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio (version 2008, 2010 ???) and that the keyboard settings are supported in the visual studio options, select the code you want to "uncrustify" and press Alt+F8. This may or may not help, but you can always select the code and then try "Shift+Tab" to remove the preceding indent. Let me know if I am wrong or missed something from your question.

Comment: This does work for sure but I have to use uncrustify to clean up a few other things too. My question is one of the last points to fullfil the code layout guideline.